# Came across the Intent parameter Uri.parse("mailto:"). What exactly does Uri.parse do?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a new intent to send email and came across this code to create an Intent.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
```

1. What does `Intent.ACTION_SEND` do?
2. What does `Uri.parse("mailto:")` do?

Comment: [Documentation of `Uri.parse(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is written to that purpose :

**What does Intent.ACTION_SEND do?**

> Activity Action: Deliver some data to someone else. Who the data is
>   being delivered to is not specified; it is up to the receiver of this
>   action to ask the user where the data should be sent.
>
> When launching a SEND intent, you should usually wrap it in a chooser
>   (through createChooser(Intent, CharSequence)), which will give the
>   proper interface for the user to pick how to send your data and allow
>   you to specify a prompt indicating what they are doing.
>
> Input: getType() is the MIME type of the data being sent. get*Extra
>   can have either a EXTRA_TEXT or EXTRA_STREAM field, containing the
>   data to be sent. If using EXTRA_TEXT, the MIME type should be
>   "text/plain"; otherwise it should be the MIME type of the data in
>   EXTRA_STREAM. Use */* if the MIME type is unknown (this will only
>   allow senders that can handle generic data streams). If using
>   EXTRA_TEXT, you can also optionally supply EXTRA_HTML_TEXT for clients
>   to retrieve your text with HTML formatting.
>
> As of JELLY_BEAN, the data being sent can be supplied through
>   setClipData(ClipData). This allows you to use
>   FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION when sharing content: URIs and other
>   advanced features of ClipData. If using this approach, you still must
>   supply the same data through the EXTRA_TEXT or EXTRA_STREAM fields
>   described below for compatibility with old applications. If you don't
>   set a ClipData, it will be copied there for you when calling
>   startActivity(Intent).
>
> Optional standard extras, which may be interpreted by some recipients
>   as appropriate, are: EXTRA_EMAIL, EXTRA_CC, EXTRA_BCC, EXTRA_SUBJECT.
>
> Output: nothing.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.SEND"

**What does Uri.parse("mailto:") do?**

> Intent (String action, 
>                   Uri uri)
>
> Create an intent with a given action and for a given data url. Note
>   that the action must be in a namespace because Intents are used
>   globally in the system -- for example the system VIEW action is
>   android.intent.action.VIEW; an application's custom action would be
>   something like com.google.app.myapp.CUSTOM_ACTION.
>
> Note: scheme and host name matching in the Android framework is
>   case-sensitive, unlike the formal RFC. As a result, you should always
>   ensure that you write your Uri with these elements using lower case
>   letters, and normalize any Uris you receive from outside of Android to
>   ensure the scheme and host is lower case.

[More information about intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)